# Excel calculate the number of calendar days between two dates for individual months

Tags: excel, date

I  need to automatically calculate the number of calendar days between two dates for individual months

EG:

```
Start        End        Jan2014 Feb2014 Mar2014 Apr2014 May2014
18/11/2013  9/03/2014       31      28    9       0        0
7/04/2014   18/05/2014      0       0     0       23       18           
....
```

Comment: What have you tried and where *exactly* are you going wrong? As it stands you've forgotten to ask a question, and the implied one, "Write my code for me?" is not how Stack Overflow works (try hiring someone instead)

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping someone could hemp with a formula to automate the calculation. I've made a start but its not working for all senarios. =IF($A3<=C$2,IF($B3>=EOMONTH(C$2,0),DAY(EOMONTH(C$2,0)),$B3-C$2),IF($B3>=EOMONTH(C$2,0),$A3-EOMONTH(C$2,0),$B3-$A3))

Answer (score 1):

you can use this formula in `C3` copied across and down if required

`=MAX(0,MIN(EOMONTH(C$2,0),$B3)-MAX(C$2,$A3+1)+1)`

Assumes that dates in `C2` and across are all 1st of the relevant month